Should questions with the sole purpose of obtaining hats be allowed?
In the chat a trend has been noticed by SEJPM:

Is this new wave of meta posts caused by the hat you get for making a meta post?

Should we be extra critical towards these types of questions? I myself can hardly imagine anyone lowering themselves to do so just to get this awesome Darth Vader hat.

Is this why you asked this question ? (to get this awesome Darth Vader hat as you wrote) :o

I wouldn't dare!

Voting on an existing post would have sufficed to get the hat.

+1 for the self-ironie in the post even though a tag "obvious-joke" is missing ;)


Should we be extra critical towards these types of questions?

I’ld say there is no need to be “extra critical”. Just handle any questions during the winter bash 2016 as usual.

In the chat a trend has been noticed by SEJPM:

Is this new wave of meta posts caused by the hat you get for making a meta post?


This points at a wrong assumption. See, the Darth Vader hat in question is issued when you post/vote on meta. This means that anyone who casts an upvote or downvote already earns the hat. There isn’t any need to actually post a Meta question. 
Personally, I can hardly imagine that someone would actually waste time and efforts to write and post a meta question just to gain the Darth Vader hat – as it can be gained with less efforts: a simple up- or downvote. 
In the unlikely case a low-quality or (let’s just call it) “useless” question would be posted here at Meta just for the purpose of hat-gaining, you can flag it accordingly so that it can be taken care of. Yet, that’s not much different from the usual way we handle things around here – which somewhat voids the need to be “extra critical”. 
TL;DR

Should we be extra critical towards these types of questions?

No. It suffices to apply common sense and to be as critical as usual.
